# Outputting a response from an Action in Javascript

Tags: javascript, response

I'm getting this back as response from a form action

```
{"actionErrors":["File uploaded exceeds maximum allowed size of 256 KB"],"fieldErrors":{},"result":"input"}
```

How do I output actionErrors and result in Javascript?

Comment: Isn't this already in JavaScript? Is it not something like `object.actionErrors`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your response content type in JSON format
Try this way

```
  var data = {"actionErrors":["File uploaded exceeds maximum allowed size of 256 KB"],"fieldErrors":{},"result":"input"};

    alert(data.actionErrors[0]);
```

If response content type not json then use `JSON.parse();` function to covert response string in JSON object format.

Comment: Cheers I had to use obj = JSON.parse(data);